# How to create maven project with pom file programmatically while creating eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating an eclipse plugin which will make a maven java project.
I have included maven natures as I want it to be a maven project with `pom.xml`.

```
IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
        description.setNatureIds(new String[] {
                     "org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature",
                     "org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature",
                     "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature",
                     "org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature",
                     "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature"});

        project.setDescription(description, monitor);
```

But it doesn't create any pom file instead I'm seeing the following lines in log:

```
16:50:00.271 [Worker-2] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Building project AA
16:50:00.271 [Worker-2] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.ProjectRegistryManager - Refreshing: [L/AA/pom.xml]
16:50:00.286 [Worker-2] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.ProjectRegistryManager - Refreshed: [L/AA/pom.xml]
16:50:00.770 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.ProjectRegistryManager - Refreshing: [L/AA/pom.xml]
16:50:00.770 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.ProjectRegistryManager - Refreshed: [L/AA/pom.xml]
```

Any help?

Comment: You'll need to create the POM and have m2e generate the Eclipse project, I think. Have you looked at the source for m2e's New Maven Project?

Comment: Can you give me any source code examples?

Comment: I just did: m2eclipse.

Comment: Can you tell me why it's showing L/AA/pom.xml? when pom is not created?

Comment: `I'm creating an eclipse plugin` is this true? You are creating a plugin for eclipse or you are creating a project using a plugin as you state in the title?